# How to store foreach variable result in php variable

Tags: php, html, cakephp-2.0

I just want to store HTML data in a PHP variable. But the problem is that the data also contains a PHP function

```
 $CartItem = "<table style='width:100%'>
<tr>
<th style='text-align:left;'><strong>Code</strong></th>
<th style='text-align:left;'><strong>ItemName</strong></th>
<th style='text-align:right;'><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
</tr>". foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){ .
 "
<tr>
<td style='text-align:left;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;'>" .echo $item["ItemCode"]; ."</td>
<td style='text-align:left;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;'><strong>" .echo $item["ItemName"];."</strong></td>
<td style='text-align:right;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;'>". echo $item["quantity"];."</td>
</tr>".
} ."


 </table>";
```

I just want to create HTML code using a PHP `foreach` loop and store them in `$CartItem`.

Please help me with correct code.

My code has an error

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in
>   C:\wamp\www\drupal-7.38\shoppingcart\initiateOrder\index.php on line
>   70

Comment: Don't concatenate the `foreach`.

Comment: then how can i read cart data

Comment: Concatenate the string in the foreach block...

Comment: Please comment the right code

Answer (score 2):

Don't concatenate your `foreach` to the string;

```
$CartItem = "<table style='width:100%'>
<tr>
<th style='text-align:left;'><strong>Code</strong></th>
<th style='text-align:left;'><strong>ItemName</strong></th>
<th style='text-align:right;'><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
</tr>";
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
  $CartItem .= "
  <tr>
  <td style='text-align:left;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;'>" . $item["ItemCode"] ."</td>
  <td style='text-align:left;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;'><strong>" . $item["ItemName"] ."</strong></td>
  <td style='text-align:right;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;'>".  $item["quantity"] ."</td>
  </tr>";
}

$CartItem .= "</table>";
```

Comment: give error on echo

Comment: Edited my/your code, `echo`s are now gone

Answer (score 2):

This is correct way to concatenate:

```
<?php
$CartItem = "<table style='width:100%'>
<tr>
<th style='text-align:left;'><strong>Code</strong></th>
<th style='text-align:left;'><strong>ItemName</strong></th>
<th style='text-align:right;'><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
</tr>"; 

foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item) {

$CartItem .= "
<tr>
<td style='text-align:left;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;'>" . $item["ItemCode"] ."</td>
<td style='text-align:left;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;'><strong>" .  $item["ItemName"] . "</strong></td>
<td style='text-align:right;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;'>" . $item["quantity"] . "</td></tr>";

} 

$CartItem .= "</table>";

echo $CartItem;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misused of concatenation. Don't concatenate `foreach` and `echo`

```
$CartItem = "<table style='width:100%'>
<tr>
<th style='text-align:left;'><strong>Code</strong></th>
<th style='text-align:left;'><strong>ItemName</strong></th>
<th style='text-align:right;'><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
</tr>";
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){ 

   $CartItem .= "
   <tr>
<td style='text-align:left;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;'>" . 
$item["ItemCode"] ."</td>
<td style='text-align:left;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;'><strong>" .
$item["ItemName"]."</strong></td>
<td style='text-align:right;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;'>".  
$item["quantity"]."</td>
</tr>";
}


    $CartItem .="</table>";
```